# How do I import a database through a Drush(PHP) script?

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to write a Drush script locally to speed up some repetitive tasks. I am running in to issues importing a database through the script. I have tried using `drush_invoke` and `drush_invoke_process` to run the equivalent of `drush sql-cli < C:/path/to/mysql.sql`.

I have tried several different variations with the `$commandline_args` and `$commandline_arguments` with no luck and Google has not been helping me much.

Does anyone have the correct syntax for this? I would also be fine with another method that works. I would prefer one that allows for a user input path to the SQL file but hard coded would work for now.

EDIT: I am using `drush scr` to run the script. Just in case it makes a difference.

EDIT 2: The accepted answer from greg_1_anderson works great. To allow for using the path to the file as an argument I found that [drupal_get_option](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!includes!context.inc/function/drush_get_option/7) works. Just add the argument `--arg_name=arg_value` like `drush scr script.php --file=path/to/file`. Then call the arg in the script file.

Full solution:

```
$file = drush_get_option('file');
$options = array(
  'file' => $file,
  'file-delete' => FALSE,
  'strict' => FALSE,
);
drush_invoke_process($self, 'sql-query', array(), $options);
```

Comment: So you're looking to execute a PHP script after executing a few SQL queries in Drush?

Comment: I am looking to run some Drush commands and make a db import (and updates) in a PHP script. I would prefer using Drush commands but I could be dissuaded. I was hoping that the sql-cli command would transfer over to the `drush_invoke_process` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you want to run some php code to import an SQL database dump from a file.  There is code that does this in the implementation of `drush sql-sync`.  It looks like [this](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.0.0-rc3/commands/sql/sqlsync.drush.inc#L266):

```
  $options = $global_options + $target_options + array(
    'file' => $destination_dump_path,
    'file-delete' => TRUE,
  );
  $return = drush_invoke_process($destination, 'sql-query', array(), $options, $backend_options);
  if ($return['error_status']) {
    // An error was already logged.
    return FALSE;
  }
```

You could also call `drush sql-sync` with appropriate options for a more full-featured solution (e.g. if you want to import a local database to a remote site).  For an import to a local site, though, it is more straightforward to simply use the snippet above, which essentially runs `drush sql-query --file=/path/to/dump.sql`.

n.b. You may simply remove (or make empty) `$global_options`, `$target_options` and `$backend_options`. You should also take of the `file-delete` flag, unless you really would like Drush to delete your sql dump for you after it has imported it (e.g. for temporary files).

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly for me. Note that because of my version I also had to add `'strict' => FALSE` to the options (although I could have removed the `'file-delete'` as well).